# How do you show that $||f + g|| \leq ||f|| + ||g||$?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that $||f + g|| \leq ||f|| + ||g||$. We are given the definition that $$||f || := \sup_{x \in E} | f(x)|.$$

So here is my approach.

By definition we have, \begin{align*}
||f + g|| & = \sup_{x \in E}|(f + g)(x)| \\
& = \sup_{x \in E}|(f(x) + g(x)| \\
& = \sup\{|f(x) + g(x)| : x \in E\}.
\end{align*}
Now suppose $\sup_{x \in E} |f(x)| := L$ and $\sup_{x \in E} |g(x)| := M.$ Then by the Approximation Property for Suprema, we know that 
$\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists x \in E$ such that  $L - \epsilon < |f(x)| \leq L$ and $M - \epsilon < |g(x)| \leq M$. Adding the two inequalities we get $(L - \epsilon) + (M - \epsilon)  < |f(x)| + |g(x)| \leq M + L$. By the triangle inequality $|f(x) + g(x)| \leq |f(x)| + |g(x)| \leq L+M$. In particular, $|f(x) + g(x)| \leq L+M.$

But this is not saying that $\sup_{x \in E} |f(x) + g(x)| \leq L + M$.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|f(x)+g(x)|\leq L+M$ for all $x$, then $L+M$ is an upper bound, so $\sup|f(x)+g(x)|\leq L+M$.

As for the argument, you don't need any $\epsilon$: for any $x$,
$$
|f(x)+g(x)|\leq|f(x)|+|g(x)|\leq L+M. 
$$

Comment: makes great sense. thank you.